# Sperman or Pearson?

Tags: spearman-rho, correlation

I have 66 samples with assigned microbiome. I also have glucose measure for each sample. Which test should I use to see correlation?

To be more specific, I would like to use program: http://qiime.org/scripts/observation_metadata_correlation.html
Which of the listed test and P-value method would you chose to test my data?

PS. Below example of microbiome data:

```
OTU ID  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
OTU_4   26892.0 7691.0  4601.0  9865.0  1827.0  7064.0
OTU_1   31797.0 7159.0  2996.0  15777.0 2298.0  8900.0
OTU_6   2572.0  2264.0  300.0   16546.0 1546.0  738.0
OTU_7   22077.0 2089.0  3326.0  1917.0  4066.0  1559.0
OTU_2   18787.0 4987.0  159.0   8361.0  7315.0  5764.0
OTU_715 61.0    10.0    13.0    59.0    0.0 19.0
OTU_862 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0
OTU_12  3195.0  1319.0  921.0   3627.0  1333.0  1173.0
OTU_31  1733.0  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
OTU_42  2180.0  152.0   0.0 5057.0  207.0   0.0
```

Comment: What variables types and values do you have?

Comment: I have OTU table (as table with number of reads assigned to each bacteria) and glucose measure for each sample.

Comment: I think user2974951 is asking whether your data is a rank (which it doesn't seem to be) or a measurable quantity, ie 5 centimeters or 11 kg or 451 individuals.  Pearson is used to find a linear relationship between measurable variables, while rank correlation finds a relationship between the ordering.

Comment: The glucose is measured in mg/dl (milligram per deciliter), and it's known for each sample S1, S2, S3, S4, S5 etc.

Comment: What are OTU ID and S1 ... S6? What do you want to compare?

Comment: S1-S6...S66 are samples, and OTU_ID is the bacteria. Each OTU represents different bacteria. The occurance of specific bacteria (OTU) is presented as number of read for each sample (eg. 26892 of reads for S1 sample in OTU_4). In addition I have a glucose measure for each sample. I would like to show that there is a correlation between the occurance of some bacteria for low/high glucose level.

Comment: So, I will go with pearson correlation but what type of p-value method should I use? Bootrapping?

Comment: So all the 66 samples fall into two categories, low and high glucose? And you want to compare these two categories? How are you going to estimate a correlation for each sample? OUT's (that is your bacteria) are not numerical, so it does not make sense to get correlations. Do you want to compare the means of each group?